# Systematic references on linearizing conditional / logical expressions

Tags: linearization, reference-request

On this site, one can usually finds questions like “How to transform my expression into linear form?” The expressions usually contain `and`, `or`, `iff`, and combines of them. But the answers are usually problem specific, making it hard to generalize them to other cases.

My questions are:

- Is there any systematic material on linearization for conditional / logical expressions?
- It seems that Constraint Programming (CP), which I am not quite familiar with, handles conditional / logical expressions more intuitively. Is there any reference on the link between CP and Mathematical Programming.

Comment: Maybe a related question: [which method has been used to automatically reformulate logical constraints in a standard MIP solver?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/8741/199)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A systematic approach is to rewrite the logical proposition in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), which somewhat automatically yields linear constraints:

$$\bigwedge_{i \in I} \bigvee_{j \in J_i} z_{ij} \iff \left(\sum_{j \in J_i} z_{ij} \ge 1 \text{ for all $i \in I$}\right)$$

Several examples are [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22conjunctive%20normal%20form%22).

A good reference is:

> Raman, R. and I.E. Grossmann, *Relation Between MILP Modelling and
> Logical Inference for Chemical Process Synthesis*, **Computers Chem.
> Engng.** 15 (1991).

Comment: Thank you, @RobPratt! This feels like magic to me. It can be very helpful for complex logical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I was also interested in this.

I found these [lecture notes](https://laurentlessard.com/teaching/cs524/slides/20%20-%20logic%20constraints%20and%20integer%20variables.pdf) online by Laurent Lessard which covers many cases. RobPratt's answer is very useful. The reason for adding these lecture notes as well is because they cover some cases where I would not be confident converting to CNF (e.g. implications).

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following documentation from YALMIP often useful:

[YALMIP -  Logics and integer-programming representations](https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/logicprogramming)

Comment: Thanks Sudix. This link contains not only logical constraints, but also "Multiplications of variables and functions" and "Representations of functions", which are useful.