# logic constraints for IP model

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, reference-request, logical-constraints

I have been struggling with the formulation of logic constraints. Is there any source you would recommend to understand the topic better or trick of formulation of the constraints?

Comment: [*Model Building in Mathematical Programming*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/model-building-in/9781118506172/) by H. Paul Williams might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single reference for Mixed Integer Programming formulations to linearize, handle logical constraints and disjunctive constraints, do Big M, etc?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/57/single-reference-for-mixed-integer-programming-formulations-to-linearize-handle)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the very useful reference mentioned by @RobPratt, the following might have also been good starting points:

- [Logics and integer-programming representations by YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/logicprogramming)
- [How do I model conditional statements in Gurobi?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-)
- [Systematic references on linearizing conditional/logical expressions](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/systematic-references-on-linearizing-conditional-logical-expressions)
- [When to use indicator constraints versus big-M approaches](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/231/when-to-use-indicator-constraints-versus-big-m-approaches-in-solving-mixed-int/259#259)

It already would be worth to search the community by the same topics to find lots of case studies.